# System.Timers.Timer strange behaviour

Tags: c#, timer

Here is a code. Run and immediately keep P pressed. You should see the first date twice. I see. And I really don't know why it is so. I would like to understand it. Could someone explain it to me in clear way ?

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Timer1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        static Timer timer;

        static int interval = 1000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.SetBufferSize(1000, 1000);

            timer = new Timer(interval);
            timer.Elapsed += Function;
            timer.Interval = interval;
            timer.Enabled = true;

            stopwatch.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

                if (key == ConsoleKey.P)
                {
                    int temp = interval - (int)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                    if (temp > 0)
                        timer.Interval = temp;

                    else
                        Function(null, null);
                }

                else
                {
                    timer.Dispose();
                    break;
                }

                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }

        static public void Function(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Interval = interval;
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say you see the first date twice. You just don't have enough resolution to know that they are different. Do `DateTime.Now.Ticks` in your `Console.WriteLine` instead. You will see a difference.

Comment: I know that they aren't equal mathematically. But why there are dates with such a short interval ?

Comment: @PatrikBak - try taking out the "else Function(null, null)"

Comment: @Les Thank you, this really works and without that the code is clear I hope. Or do you have another sugestions how to improve that :) ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is written, you have two paths to Function().  One path is when the timer actually elapses and the Function() is "handled" as a result.  The other path is when

```
interval - stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

is not greater than 0, in which case you call Function() directly.

It looks like you are using the System.Timers.Timer.  This is run on a threadpool thread.  Since you have multiple threads running, both can call Function().  You may think you guarded against that by resetting your internal and stopwatch in Function(), but the Console.WriteLine() is enough to allow one thread to defer and let the other thread run (and on multiprocessor computers, both threads can run at once on different processors).

By the nature of your logic, it is guaranteed that the timer interval will fire (call the handler) at nearly the same time that your interval test reaches 0, so you can expect it to run through both paths.

The example doesn't look very useful.  Is it simply to understand timers?  You can change the interval of the time if you like, but why bother when you are changing it to roughly what it was (or should be)?

Comment: I know but I can't explain why they both occur in such a short interval (less than one second)

Comment: I just wanted to program timer which I can pause and resume whenever I want without losing time (this is more useful when the interval is longer). P represents "pause" and while loop resuming. Thank for explantation.